# Error of Telegram - [File lives in another DC]

Tags: node.js, telegram

I have a strange error in my Nodejs script:

```
import { TelegramClient } from "telegram/index.js";
import { StringSession } from "telegram/sessions/index.js";
import input from "input";
import { promises as fs } from 'fs';

  const channel = await client.getEntity("https://t.me/anyname")
  const db = [await client.getMessages(channel)]

  for (const msgs of db) {
    for (const msg of msgs) {
      function getRandomInt(max) {
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * max);
      }
      const bufferx = await client.downloadMedia(msg)
      const fileName = 'file' + getRandomInt(10000000000000)
      await fs.writeFile('media/' + fileName, bufferx);
      const buffer = await client.downloadMedia(msg, {
        progressCallback: console.log
      })
    }
}
```

It downloads files from the telegram channel, but not all due to an error - **[INFO] - [File lives in another DC]**

(this is an incomplete script, but I think the essence is clear)

Any thoughts?